# bind client socket to same IP:port, what happened?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I know that TCP/UDP socket identified by 5-tuple, (**protocol**, **src IP**, **src PORT**, **dst IP**, **dst PORT**).
I thought that, theoretically, two TCP client socket **on same src IP:src PORT** can exist if dst IP:dst PORT differ.
So, out of curiosity, I did a simple test:

1. run web servers on 127.0.0.1:8000 and 127.0.0:8001
2. run client socket program that requests to server 8000.
3. run same client program on **same src IP:src port**, but requests to server 8001.

Server return message every second for 10 seconds for keeping connection.
Both client are `bind()`ed manually, set `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Because it cannot be decided which process to send each packet to, I expected the output of the returned message to be messed up in each client process.
But the message was sent correctly to each of the clients who made the request.

I can't understand how it worked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually answered your own question:

> I know that TCP/UDP socket identified by 5-tuple, (protocol, src IP, src PORT, dst IP, dst PORT)

The first client's 5-tuple differs from the second client's 5-tuple because the "dst PORT" is different.

Comment: Yes, they are different. But if port is same, how is it determined which process to forward to when demultiplexed?

Comment: @mishy there's nothing to demultiplex because for the networking stack, these are two distinct TCP streams. Generally speaking, the kernel will look up which 5-tuple (which it can determine from the TCP/IP headers) belongs to which process.

Comment: Ah, the kernel uses all elements of the 5-tuple, not just dst IP:dst PORT to find the destination process?

Comment: @mishy yes, at least that's how it seems to works on Linux. See [this document](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/netreads/path-of-packet/Network_stack.pdf) (search for `__tcp_v4_lookup`).

Comment: Now I understand. Perhaps I thought all destination ports like listening ports.

Comment: just one more question, is it true that the listening port cannot be same between other processes, unlike the above case?

Comment: @mishy for listening ports, from what I know the "unique identifier" is the combination of the address and port that are being listened on. So a process that listens on `127.0.0.1:12345` can co-exist next to a process that listens on `192.168.1.1:12345` (or, to my surprise, on `0.0.0.0:12345`).

Comment: for listening port: unique `dstIP`:`dstPORT`, for others: unique `5-tuple`. now it's clear. thanks.